# Barra de progresso para procedimento armazenado em c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um projecto que faz actualização de dados atravez de um procedimento armazenado (delete, insert, update) com duração longa não determinada. Eu gostaria de apresentar uma barra de progresso com tempo não determinado durante o periodo de execução do procedimento. Não tenho experiência em barra de progresso. Alguém pode explicar como se pode implementar?

```
private void btActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _IDSave = _ID;
    _CartaoSave = _Cartao;

    // Chama o form onde se escolhe o ano de Contabilidade (cada ano um database!)
    frmEscolhaDeAnoContabilidade frmRefresh = new frmEscolhaDeAnoContabilidade();
    frmRefresh.ShowDialog();

    string dataBaseName = frmRefresh.dataBaseName;
    string anoContabilidade = frmRefresh.anoContabilidade;

    if (dataBaseName.Length > 0)
    {
        string timeRefresh; 
        string deletedRec;
        string newRec;
        string updatedRec;
        string errorMessage;

        string resultText;

        // Tornar visivel e por a funcionar a barra de progresso
        progressBarRefresh.Visible = true;

        progressBarAdatfrissites.Show(); // É necessário?


        // Chamo assim o procedimento armazenado
        General2.RefreshCartaoByYear(dataBaseName);

        // Findar a barra de progresso

        if (General2.DsRefreshCartaoByYear.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            timeRefresh = General2.RefreshCartaoByYear.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TimeRefresh"].ToString();
            deletedRec = General2.RefreshCartaoByYear.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DeletedRec"].ToString();
            newRec = General2.RefreshCartaoByYear.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NewRec"].ToString();
            updatedRec = General2.RefreshCartaoByYear.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UpdatedRec"].ToString();
            errorMessage = General2.RefreshCartaoByYear.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ErrorMessage"].ToString();

            if (errorMessage.Length > 0)
            {
                resultText = "Sem resultado! \n" +
                             "Erro: " + errorMessage;
            }
            else
            {
                resultText = "Frissítés eredmény: \n" + 
                             "Időpont: " + timeRefresh + ", Könyvelési év: " + konyvalesiEv + "\n" +
                             "Törölt tételek száma: " + deletedRec + ", Új teételek száma: " + newRec + ", Módosult tételek száma: " + updatedRec;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(resultText);

            AktualiyarDataGridView();

            dgvCartao.Rows
                      OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                      .Where(x => x.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString() == _IDSave)
                      .ToArray<DataGridViewRow>()[0]
                       .Selected = true;
        }
    }
}


namespace Total_accounts
{
  class General2
  {
    public static void RefreshCartaoByYear( string _Database)
    {
        SqlCommand commSQLCommand = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter daSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommandBuilder cbSQLCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
        SqlConnection connSQLServer1 = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataReader dataSQLDataReader = null;

        dsRefreshCartaoByYear = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            connSQLServer1.ConnectionString = General.STRConnection; //strConnection;
            connSQLServer1.Open();
            commSQLCommand.Connection = connSQLServer1;
            commSQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            commSQLCommand.CommandText = "spRefreshCartaoByYear";

            commSQLCommand.CommandTimeout = timeOut;

            daSqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = commSQLCommand;
            cbSQLCommandBuilder.DataAdapter = daSqlDataAdapter;

            dsRefreshCartaoByYear.Clear();
            commSQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strpmDatabase", _Database);
            daSqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsRefreshCartaoByYear, "tableRefreshCartaoByYear");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connSQLServer1 != null)
            {
                connSQLServer1.Close();
            }
            if (dataSQLDataReader != null)
            {
                dataSQLDataReader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ao que parece, o comando está sendo executado na mesma thread do form, pra colocar uma barra de progresso, você teria que executar em outra thread, ou exibir outra janela com o a barra

Comment: Eu tentei implementar muitos dos exemplos que li, infelizmente nűao consegui fazer o que quero. Podes dar mais pormenores? Ficaria muito grato. Obrigado pela sua contribuição

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar uma tarefa assíncrona para realizar um procedimento longo. Isto pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

Adicionar um retorno do tipo "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" no método que realiza o procedimento longo para que ele possa ser 'awaitable'/aguardável :

```
public async Task MeuProcedimentoLongo()
{
  // código...
}
```

---

Assim você poderia chamar o procedimento em outro lugar:

```
public async void MeuMetodo() 
{
    // criacao e inicializacao da ProgressBar
    var pb = new ProgressBar();
    pb.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    pb.Visible = true;

    // aguarde o metodo realizar o procedimento longo
    await MeuProcedimentoLongo();
    pb.Visible = false;
}
```

Ou ainda poderia chamá-lo por delegação de tarefa:

```
public void MeuMetodo()
{
    // criacao e inicializacao da ProgressBar

    // aguarde a tarefa ser realizada
    Task.Run(async ()=> { await MeuProcedimentoLongo(); });
}
```

---

> Note ainda que a palavra reservada `async` é utilizada quando deseja-se aguardar uma tarefa dentro de um método!